# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly, nuget-package, asp.net-identity-2

A project was handled to me. I am using VS 2015 on windows 8 machine. I am trying to run the website which uses Framework V 4.6. However, the following error appears:

**Error**[image: Error Description for Identitymodel jwt]

**Stack Trace**
[image: Stack Trace Error]

I am trying to solve this issue:

1. I have checked the projects in the solution that are referencing: '*System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt*' v 4.0. The projects that were refencing this dll was actually v 1.0, so i uninstalled the v 4.0 for a specific project and re-installed v 1.0 using Nuget Manager.
2. I also tried to clear Temp Directory Files: *AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files*, but this also didn't work.

Anybody can propose a solution?

Comment: Have you tried BindingRedirect to handle multiple assembly versions? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, but this was not the reason, Binding Redirect was already specified

Comment: having the same problem